# How to move mails out of a broken account?

Tags: mail.app, email

I'm facing a serious problem on a clients MacBook Pro (High Sierra). He has transferred his domain to a new provider, where I recreated his email accounts and added them in Mac Mail before the migration took place, so he had both accounts in his list. I expected to do a clean mail migration once new messages started pouring into the new account.
However, I seem unable to move the messages from the (now defunct) old account into the new one. The move progress stays at 1/316, taking over an hour now.
I also attempted to export the inbox and sent folders, which produces some empty mbox files. Reimporting them should - according to the Apple help pages - create a new *imported* folder in the folder list, but it does not.

Is this expected behaviour? How can I get those emails into the new account?

Comment: May not be the answer in your case, but about a year ago I experienced pretty much the exact same scenario - except that it was an iMac recently upgraded to macOS Sierra. In my case, it actually turned out to be a hard drive on the way out. After replacing the internal hard drive I was able to get it all working okay from a Time Machine backup. So *maybe* run Apple Hardware Test or Apple Diagnostics to make sure there's nothing else also going on.

Comment: Hey @Monomeeth, thank your for the suggestion, but the drive is fine in my case.